# Как пишется слово

Tags: орфография

Как пишется слово "двеннадцатиклассник"?

Comment: Двенадцатиклассник  - с одним н.

Answer (score 2):

Вы всё правильно написали. Только у нас в России вроде 12-го класса нет. А так, если существует где-то, то так и пишется.